# FPC protocol to HDMI for pi

Tags: pi-3

Can you please help understand how I can connect 39pin FPC LCD to raspberry pi3? I guess it is not possible to connect LCD directly to pi display connector.

Is there FPC to HDMI converter module, which I can buy and than connect LCD to HDMI output of pi3?

If not, than what other solutions exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect an FPC protocol adapter to the raspberry pi GPIO interface.

For and example see: http://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-LCD-to-Raspberry-Pi-Without-Breakout-Board/